# Dt and dd inline not work in outlook email body

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I want create outlook email by using the html format, but some of the html style can't work in outlook email.

I have a test code like below:
`<dl><dt style="float: left">ColumnA: </dt><dd style="padding-left:30px">sahjdhsj; kahdjkshakjdhkasjhdkjshakjhdska; sa dsah ashkdj sadksajhd dksad asdhsahdsahodsad ashkjdhsa asd ipientList, string originalSubject, string recallLink</dd><dt style="float: left">ColumnB:</dt><dd style="Margin-left:30px">lack hot drink gjg daskahdkjahd asd gkashdksahdsakjhdsadsdsad</dd></dl>`

When I test it in https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro, it can work as expected:
**P1**
[image]
but when I use it as the outlook email body, it will show like:
**P2**
[image: ![enter image description here]

Anyone know what caused the different behavior in outlook email? I just want it show as **P1**

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve that layout in Outlook for Windows is to use tables. It recognises dt and dl (https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-lists/) but not changes to display modes or floats (https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display/ and https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-float/). Therefore, they will always both be stuck in their default `display:block` modes, that take the whole line.

You could use different code for Outlook on Windows by using their conditional code.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. Unfortunately not all CSS properties are supported in Word. For example, the `float` property is treated like unknown in Word. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.